# Adding item into database without inputting in the text box

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to figure out how to insert a default item which is "Item Code" into my 'List' database instantaneously after clicking the add button. I only managed to do is insert the string/char that I have entered in the text box. Though, when I click the 'add' button without typing in anything inside the text box, I get this error:

```
ValueError at /
The view home.views.index didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

Here are my codes so far:

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class List(models.Model):
    item = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.item
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import List
from .forms import ListForm
from django.contrib import messages


def index(request):
    context = {
        'items': List.objects.all()
    }

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ListForm(request.POST or None)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, ('Item has been added to the list.'))
            return render(request, 'home/index.html', context)
    else:
        return render(request, 'home/index.html', context)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import List

class ListForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = List
        fields = [
            'item',
            'date'
        ]
```

index.html

```
<h1>To do list</h1>
{% if messages %}    
    {% for message in messages %}
        <p> {{ message }} </p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}

<ul>
    {% if items %}
    {% for item in items %}
        <li>{{ item.item }}</li>
        <li>{{ item.date }}</li>
        <br>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
</ul>
<form method="POST">{% csrf_token %} 
    <input type="text" name="item">
    <input type="submit" value="Add">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the else statement and unindent the return. You always want to return that rendered template, except when you redirect after a successful post.

Comment: Thank you for that! I don't get the error anymore every time I click the 'add' button. 

I would like to ask how can I establish a default item so that it will be the one that will be inserted into the database every time I don't enter anything in the text box?